# drawLine() draws lines outside of its drawing area

Tags: android, android-canvas

[image: Before Scrolling]

[image: After scrolling]

[image: Layout Overview]

I have a custom LinearLayout class that overwrites its onDraw() method. It goes into each row of ListView, as shown in the third picture. Everything looks great until I scroll the listview upward. Then the dotted line rendered from drawLine() call gets drawn over LinearLayout that sits above ListView. This is strange because the orange rounded rectangles get drawn without this problem.

My custom LinearLayout does call "this.setWillNotDraw(false);" I tried calling "LinearLayout1.postinvalidate();" in the ListView's onScrollListener, but it fails to get the top LinearLayout to redraw. What can I do to prevent the lines from getting drawn on top of LinearLayout?

Comment: Get the scrolled value of the listview and add an offset to the drawing method. Could help you more if you show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to resort to the following workaround:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap offScreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas offScreenCanvas = new Canvas(offScreenBitmap);

    // do your drawings onto offScreenBitmap here

    Paint offScreenPaint = new Paint();
    offScreenPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    offScreenPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    offScreenPaint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(offScreenBitmap,0,0,offScreenPaint);
}
```

My code actually prepares offScreenBitmap at the beginning, because its contents are static and need to be drawn only once.